# How to extract unique values of columns and rows in Google Sheets?

Tags: database, google-sheets

I am trying to extract the unique names of every company listed on the following Fortune 500 index since 1955. Many names are repeated since they stayed in the index for years at a time. The only function I can find in Google Sheets is UNIQUE, but it only works on single columns, not entire datasets. Any suggestions?

[image: Spreadsheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FLATTEN()` with `UNIQUE()` function.

```
=UNIQUE(FLATTEN(B2:U))
```

Comment: I have just tested it. Thanks for saving me the time!

Comment: @NickW Glad to know!